# Self-Signed SSL for my site's API access

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

In ordinary site , if i use Self-Signed SSL cert, the browser will ask to accept the certificate right? What about if i use this on my site that is accessed via API , will their client application do the same thing(pop-up the browser) or will just consume my API the normal way?

THanks in advance!

Comment: This depends on how your client is implemented. Most SSL stacks let you configure the set of trusted certificates, so you can import your own into it. We'd need more details regarding the language/framework use by your client application to be more specific.

Comment: "Most SSL stacks let you configure the set of trusted certificates"
- i'm using self-signed certificate

The client apps are all web-based, some are written in rails, some are in php.

Comment: You should be able to add your self-signed certificate to the set of trusted certificates in any of them. How to do so should be described will probably be slightly different in each case.